# Add coupon code to an existing Item in Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, coupon-codes

I am currently working on adding a discount for an existing order which is not invoiced yet in Magento admin panel. To do that I thought it is better to use Coupon codes. What I am trying to do is adding a coupon code for an existing order to make a discount on that order.

Till now I have added the coupon code input box into Order control panel. I need to connect that field with the Coupon controller and add a new function to add coupon code for an existing order. Is this the correct thing to do to make a discount on an existing order or is there a better way to do that? Is there anyone who can guide me to accomplish that?

Cheers

Comment: you can also edit the price for each item in the order

Comment: I can not do that in current admin panel order view. It lets me change only shipping and billing addresses. Do you know how can I do what you said?

Comment: When viewing an order in the backend you have a button called Edit. If you click it, the existing order will be canceled, and a new one will be created with same user details, and there you can add the items with a custom price

Comment: I see, I am aware of that but this is not exactly what I want. I want to be able to make 100 Euro discount in total cart or edit the price without cancelling and recreating the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I created a module to substruct the amount that I want to discount from the order totals. I added a textfield into order view and used the value of it to make the discount if it is filled. It works pretty good. I am setting the value of the textfield to "discount" field of the order object.